# Is StackExchange where we get support for elementary OS?

Tags: desktop

Hello everyone is this the correct place to get help with elementary OS?

It seems the elementary forums is not much help asking any questions there. Not really sure why they would have a forum if there's no one responding to anyone questions.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4):

The forum is a third party thing and has no affiliation with the elementary team.

If you go to https://elementary.io/support you will see that the place they tell you to go to have frequent questions answered, is here, Ask elementary on Stackexhange.

However: please note that no one is getting paid for providing support here, and as such, this is all volunteers pitching in.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, yes I'm aware no one is getting payed for helping out but just wanted to know were to go for answers. is there a main link for Elementary here on Stackexchange? have a great day

Comment: The elementary OS support site links directly to elementaryos.stackexchange.com

Comment: Since there's no commercial support, this site is as official as support gets at the moment.

Comment: There is also subreddit, linked on the elementary website.